# In angular when i use observable subscribe method to get the data from the custom API it was looping/calling infinitely

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, angular7

**The below code is going into the infinite loop**

I'm trying to populate the data into the angular material table, and the angular service is working absolutely fine.

I found this issue by looking into the console log(infinity loop).

```js
export class RosterDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

    dataFetch;
    data;

    constructor(private fetchDataService: FetchdataService) {
        super();
        console.log('data getting');
    }

    connect(): Observable<RosterShiftModel[]> {
        this.dataFetch = this.fetchDataService.getRosterTable().subscribe(data =>
        this.data = data
    );
        return this.data;
    }

    disconnect() {
        this.dataFetch.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**In the below code subscribe method is removed** and it is working fine, Data fetching from the server.

```js
export class RosterDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    dataSourceRoster;
    dataFetch;
    constructor(private fetchDataService: FetchdataService) {
        super();
    }

    connect(): Observable<RosterShiftModel[]> {
        return this.fetchDataService.getRosterTable();
    }

    disconnect() {
    }
}
```

**Here is the service method**

```js
getRosterTable(): Observable<OptionsModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<OptionsModel[]>('/get/getrosterinfo');
}
```

*I wanted to know, what is happening behind the scenes, and how to fix it?*

Comment: Apologize the service method which I was posted is the wrong one. It should be --> getRosterTable(). Rest all are the same only the api is different

Comment: You cannot use subscribe inside service, it should be map and response should be returned to component. please update the correct code.

Comment: @Rajath I edited your question but you can do so yourself :) Now, that `connect` method from your custom `DataSource` must return an observable, so why do you need to subscribe there? What is `this.data` and why is it not declared?

Comment: Your `connect` method is returning data, but data is defined asynchronously.

Comment: apologize guys I'm not able to edit my question! @Jeto sorry, while modifying the code I removed this.data from the declaration section. Thank you for your warm response guys.

Comment: @Rajath Weird that you can't edit it, what's happening?

Comment: Sorry @Jeto, code is now updated.